# Workflow task assigned to user in wrong domain

Tags: 2010, workflow, 2016, domain, trusted-domain

I'm currently tasked with upgrading an app that has two domains, from 2010 to 2016 SharePoint. One of the problems that was present in 2010 version is that when user is present in both domain X and Y, where X is central domain and Y the trusted one, so something like this:

```
domainx\userlogin
domainy\userlogin
```

When this users trusted domain (Y) account is assigned to the workflow task, he gets an email about that, but workflow task is visible for him only when he logs in via his central domain account (X).

The only idea that I have to solve this one is to put a filter on people picker, so only domainx users will be able to be assigned tasks, but is there any other way to solve that?

Comment: How do you assign permission in WF. Are you using the FQDN of the domain or just username (I assume in both domains they are the same) I have been working with multi forest and we haven't had that problem, but we always specified the full domain\username.

Comment: @MarekSarad Just like you said, just a username, which is the same in both domains. It can of course be solved by providing domain name like you said, but I'm searching for something "user proof" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the domain name with the user. As you use only username the system is using first result which is from the other domain. (maybe because of alphabetical sorting) As user names are unique within the domain the only way to ensure that this user is selected is using domain\username during assignment.